# How to check Java version of the Docker container?

Tags: java, docker

I'm using containers built from external images provided by a coworker. The whole application is a testing instance of a production environment. I need to know which version of Java is running inside a container. I assume that is something like:

```
docker container_name java -version
```

But this is not a proper command. I will be grateful for your help and advice how to check it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What you can do:

Check the dockerfile of your coworker to see which base image he is relying on. The base image tag usually describes the version.

Another approach is to `docker exec containerId java -version`.

Answer (score 8):

You need to execute your command sort of "remotely" imagine you have another subsystem on your host OS.

To do this you can do

`docker exec container_name java -version` - from the documentation of docker

> **docker exec** - run a command in a running container.

Or you can simply execute bash if your container is Linux and execute more commands if you like

`docker exec -it container_name bash`

again from the documentation:

> **--tty , -t**  - Allocate a pseudo-TTY
>
> **--interactive , -i**        Keep STDIN open even if not attached

Resources: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/

Answer (score 4):

```
docker exec container_name java -version
```

Answer (score 3):

show java version

```
[root@localhost docker-java]# docker images
REPOSITORY                        TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
openjdk                           8                   09df0563bdfc        10 days ago         488MB 
python                            latest              0a3a95c81a2b        10 days ago         932MB

[root@localhost docker-java]# docker run -it --rm openjdk:8 bash
root@a51edd412d60:/# java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_232"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_232-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.232-b09, mixed mode)
root@a51edd412d60:/# exit
exit
```

show python version

```
[root@localhost docker-java]# docker run -it --rm python:latest bash
 root@1e645b65683b:/# python -V
 Python 3.8.0
```